# не работает телеграмм бот на java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telebot

**Доброго времени суток. Никак не получается запустить бота, прошу о помощи
Вот написанный класс мэйн**

```
     import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
        System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1" );
        System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "9150" );
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegram = new TelegramBotsApi();

        Bot Bot = new Bot();

        }
    }
```

**Класс, где создаю бот**а

```
     import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        update.getUpdateId();
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
        if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("Привет")) {
            sendMessage.setText("привет,чем могу помочь?");
            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {

        return "RolBot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {

        return "1128733682:AAFgmIoYiWd-Pa2iIXDBKesUAO3qYFRzBOQ";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.28</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Rolbot1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

**И вот, что я получаю при запуске**

```
  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.2/guice-4.2.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Открываю телеграмм, пишу /start, затем "привет" - никакой реакции**

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
```